# How to parse svg's from a string

Tags: angular

Im trying to create a simple icon component which has an array of svg's and the selected just gets parsed to the html.

This is my html:

```
<div [innerHTML]="icon"></div>
```

And this is my ts:

```
export class IconComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() name;
  icon;

  constructor() { }

  icons = [{
    title: 'done',
    icon: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="white"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path fill="currentColor" d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/></svg>'
  },
  {
    title: 'clear',
    icon: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="white"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path fill="currentColor" d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"/></svg>'
  }];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.icon = this.icons.find(s => s.title === this.name) ? this.icons.find(s => s.title === this.name).icon : null;
  }
}
```

Somehow when i use the component it doesnt show anything, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need inject [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) in the constructor

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'
..
constructor(public domSanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
```

And use

```
<div [innerHTML]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(icon)"></div>
```

or

```
iconSafe=this.domSanitizer('......')
//and use
<div [innerHTML]="iconSafe"></div>
```